# Epidemiology and the corona virus

Tags: exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

How would we model the current spread and death rate of the novel corona virus in the UK: [Covid19 death, case graph](https://covid19info.live/uk/)?

Is there a way we could do this or are there too many unknown variables that we don’t know how to account for?

Could we use data from other countries like Italy? Or are there too many dissimilarities, like average age of the population?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "the current situation"?  What are you wanting to model?  Note that any model worth studying will have assumptions and limitations, but over-specifying a model by accounting for every variable is not the way to fix this issue (it actually makes the model's predictive power worse)

Comment: The contact process is probably one of the simplest mathematical model of infection. Google or Wikipedia has details, search “contact process math” or likewise.

Comment: You can take a look at [this simple model](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354969/50073). According to that model and information-theoretic considerations, [the current data for UK](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/uk) has a 2-piece best-fit curve with the 1st piece up to 20 Mar and the 2nd piece from 21 Mar to 28 Mar, but the 2nd piece is more or less exponential so the model is not able to give a good prediction. The optimization says ≈350000 total cases with peak growth 2 weeks from today, but there is little confidence in that number except in terms of its order of magnitude.

Comment: And just to address the question about comparing countries, that doesn't work at all because the outbreak progression depends a lot on culture and connectivity. All you can expect to see is that each time interval for each country will roughly resemble some part of a tanh curve as explained in the linked post.

Comment: I'm not sure why the non-linear solver I'm using didn't find a better fit than the one I got earlier (even though I did say I cannot give a good prediction). The better fit for the data up to 28 Mar was a 3-piece curve that predicts ≈29000 total cases. Best fit for data up to 29 Mar predicts ≈24000 total cases. For both, the peak growth rate was around 28 Mar, so if the trend continues we have reasonable confidence in the new predictions.

Comment: Am wondering the same thing.  Have made some progress: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798972/epidemiology-and-double-exponential-sigmoid-error-bars

Comment: Let k be per capital deaths t days into 2020, $k=(0.00061)e^{\frac{(19.9155)}{(-0.0547)}e^{-0.0547t}}$ 
Until the second wave hits next month.

Answer (score 1):

**Some elements of answer**

When you use the word **model**, the big question is always with which level of approximation.

At least [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSqIwXl6IjQ) presents in a didactic way a basic epidemic model.

And [this article](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/medicine/sph/ide/gida-fellowships/Imperial-College-COVID19-NPI-modelling-16-03-2020.pdf), some background on the UK political debate around the way to manage the epidemic.

Comment: Ah thank you!! I was quite curious but I suppose I didn’t factor in the fact there would be a variety of approximations, which is very foolish of me, give that it is a model and all models have intrinsicly in them some degree of approximation